# Ubuntu 7z switch is not working

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, 7zip

According to this manual (https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/bs.htm) this command should've worked but it doesn't work:

```
ubuntu$ 7z x my.zip -og -bsp2


Error:
Incorrect command line
ubuntu$ apt-cache policy p7zip-full
p7zip-full:
  Installed: 9.20.1~dfsg.1-4.2
  Candidate: 9.20.1~dfsg.1-4.2
  Version table:
 *** 9.20.1~dfsg.1-4.2 500
        500 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I searched documentations and googled but couldn't find the reason it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

`-bs` switch isn't available in ubuntu 16.04 p7zip-full package. I downloaded the latest version which is 16 as of writing this. The latest version has the switch.

https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/bugs/209/